# Neyman-Pearson Lemma to find the MP test of a beta distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

My problem:

Let $X$ be a random sample of size $n=1$ from a beta distribution with parameters $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=\theta$. If we wish to test $H_{0}:\theta=1$ against $H_{1}:\theta=3$ with $95\%$ confidence, find the most powerful (MP) test and compute the area of rejection.

My work so far:

First I note that for a beta distribution, there will be a pdf of the form

$$f\left(x, \alpha, \beta\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha+\beta\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(\beta\right)}x^{\alpha-1}\left(x-1\right)^{\beta-1}.$$

Then, from the Neyman-Pearson Lemma,

$$\frac{L_{0}}{L_{1}} < k$$

where $L_{0}=f\left(x;\alpha=1, \beta=1\right)$ and $L_{1}=f\left(x;\alpha=1, \beta=3\right)$.

This gives us

$$\frac{\frac{\Gamma\left(1+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(1\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(1\right)}x\left(x-1\right)}{\frac{\Gamma\left(1+3\right)}{\Gamma\left(1\right)\cdot\Gamma\left(3\right)}x\left(x-1\right)^{2}} <k $$

after reducing this we have
$$\frac{\frac{1}{1}x\left(1-x\right)}{\frac{3}{2}x\left(1-x\right)^2}=\frac{2}{3\left(1-x\right)}<k$$

$$\implies x > \underbrace{1-\frac{2}{3k}}_{k'}$$

so we reject $H_{0}$ if $x>k'$.

Now to find the critical region, we integrate

$$\int^{\infty}_{k'} f\left(x;\alpha=1, \beta=1\right) dx=\alpha=0.05 $$

however, when I integrate this it just diverges. Did I make a mistake in calculating $k'$? Am I setting up the integral correctly?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake with the exponents in the beta density.  When $\alpha = \beta = 1$, then $$f(x,1,1) = \frac{\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1)} x^{1 - 1} (1 - x)^{1 - 1} = 1.$$  Similarly, $$f(x,1,3) = \frac{\Gamma(4)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(3)} x^{1-1} (1-x)^{3-1} = 3(1-x)^2.$$  So the likelihood ratio is $$\frac{1}{3(1-x)^2}.$$  Hence the rejection criterion is $$x < 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3k}} = k'.$$

At this point, you would need to observe that the support of $X$ is $[0,1]$; so the rejection region takes on the form $R = [0, k')$.  Since we need the Type I error to be $\alpha = 0.05$, we require $$0.05 = \Pr[X \in R \mid H_0] = \Pr[0 \le X < k' \mid \alpha = \beta = 1] = k',$$ hence $k' = 0.05$ and the rejection region is $R = [0, 0.05)$ for the UMP.

What is the power of this test?  It is simply $$\Pr[X \in R \mid H_1] = \Pr[0 \le X < 0.05 \mid \alpha = 1, \beta = 3] = \int_{x=0}^{0.05} 3(1-x)^2 \, dx = \frac{1141}{8000} \approx 0.142625.$$  As you can see, this UMP is not very powerful at all; but when you consider that this is based off a *single* observation, we understand why.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I can see how that mistake made a big change in the result, and I also feel really dumb for not catching that. Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it.